# Laravel Eloquent: How do I refactor this eager load query into model scope method?

Tags: php, laravel-5, eager-loading

I have a `Card` model which has many notes. And each note has an author. I am eager loading an individual card in a `show` action in my `CardsController` like so:

```
$card = $card->load(['notes' => function($query){
   $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->limit(8);
}, 'notes.author']);
```

This query works. I want to now refactor this into a model scope so I can just call `$card = Card::popular()` in my controller. So add this method to my `Card` model:

```
public function scopePopular()
    {
        $results = $this->with(['notes' => function($query){
            $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->limit(8);
        }, 'notes.author']);

        return $results;
    }
```

This messes up everything. I start getting unreadable template errors, when nothing should really break.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the `$results` object ? Is it what you are expecting ? Because you are using a `with` instead of a `load`

Comment: no - I use that for debugging - it doesn't return expected results

Comment: Also shouldnt it be `public static function` ?

Comment: I am new to scopes. If I add `static`, I can't use $this anymore

Comment: You are calling `::popular()` which is static, but in your `scopePopular` you are trying to call a referenced object.. Which a static method will have no reference to..

Comment: ok so how do I call the scope if it's not static?

Comment: Does it need to be static ? You could pass the object into scopePopular, then instead of `$this` you use the passed in variable, then return the result, as I see you're not manipulating `$this` so it doesnt need to be referenced..

Comment: Keep it as static, but use `self::` instead of `$this->`

Comment: @aynber I never knew about that!! ^^

Comment: could someone please just try posting an answer?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use it as a static function and still be able to access the static methods within the class, use `self::` instead of `$this->`.

```
public function scopePopular()
{
    $results = self::with(['notes' => function($query){
        $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->limit(8);
    }, 'notes.author']);

    return $results;
}
```

Comment: how do I call this from the controller?

Comment: You can still use `Card::popular()`.

Comment: I need it to return the exact same data as it did when I called the data from the controller. Now I get `Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$title (View: /home/vagrant/storm/resources/views/cards/show.blade.php)`

Comment: this actually returns all notes for all cards or something

Comment: @AmitErandole are you *sure* your not looking to use `load` instead of `with` ?

Comment: Now that I think about it, the scope would go on Notes, not Card. You'll have to call it through that, instead. https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#query-scopes might give you a few hints on that.